# Strange Windows 10 error 0x80070570

Tags: windows, windows-10

My PC has an SSD and a hard drive. Everything works flawlessly on them.

The following is strange behavior on a USB drive.
If I create a new folder and take the default name "New Folder", everything works flawlessly - I can add or delete files in the folder and I can delete this folder after creating it.

However, if I create a new folder and name it as I wish (e.g., "My folder"), I cannot do anything with it. I cannot add files to it and I cannot even delete it. I always get a 0x80070570 error as follows:
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Get the PC Manufacturer's Driver Update App and update all drivers. Restart at the end and test.

Comment: I put together this PC.  It has an Intel I5 CPU and Asus P8H77M motherboard.

Comment: You need to find driver updates for all the major parts as the error is normally a driver error.

Comment: You may need to back up and reinstall Windows. There is some possibility major drivers will be update along the way. Consider this approach.

Comment: Does the error occur with all attached USB devices, or just one?  If just one, have you tried to reformat the USB thumb drive?  Also, have you tried temporarily disabling your anti-virus software?  Sometimes AV software can hold temporary file/folder locks while scanning.

Comment: @leeharvey1 No, only that USB drive. I am reformatting the drive now.